# Google tables scripts span

Tags: google-apps-script

Google tables scripts
I can not figure out how to get the coordinates of the area to which the cell belongs. Example:
   from a1to a5 - unification. (span cell)
If I chose a2 how do I find out the coordinates of its interconnection (a1: a5)?

Comment: A cell is just a Range in a Sheet - does getA1Notation() not return the "A1:A5" you are expecting?

Comment: If I have merged the cells a1 - a5 (the dimensions of the union are unknown). I chose a2, I need to find out whether the cell is inside the join and get its size (a1-a5)

Comment: I don't know size merge.... a1-a10... or a2-a8.  I have select cell a3 - it join range? yes! size merge? a2-a8! ok =)